Loading data from a 50 gb csv file to redshift or snowflake table
I have a question regarding processing a 50 csv file on AWS S3 using pyspark and loading to redshift stage Layer then transformed layer and so on.
How do we design such a pipeline, what ETL workflow will be used?

Redshift copies directly from S3, do not read the data out of S3 then back into redshift, thats an anti pattern
